# AttributeError and TypeError in KivyMD (Python)

Tags: python, kivy, typeerror, attributeerror, kivymd

I got this Error when running my `KivyMD` app. I'm new to this field and don't know to resolve it and I have no any idea about it. But I want to prevent from this Error. I have tried many ways from the Internet. But nothing was succed. Who can resolve this Issue? Please...

**.kv**

```
MDScreen:
    name: "welcome"
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color : 1, 1, 1, 1
        Carousel:
            id: carousel
            on_current_slide: app.current_slide(self.index)
            MDFloatLayout:
                Image:
                    source: "Assets/1.png"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
                MDLabel:
                    text: "1"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": .087}
            MDFloatLayout:
                Image:
                    source: "Assets/2.png"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
                MDLabel:
                    text: "2"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": .087}
```

**.py**

```
class DiaryApp (MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file('kv/Diary.kv'))
        return screen_manager

    def on_start(self):
        carousel = self.root.ids.carousel
        carousel.loop = True
        Clock.schedule_interval(carousel.load_next, 3.0)

    def current_slide(self, index):
        pass

    def next(self):
        self.root.ids.carousel.load_next(mode="next")

DiaryApp().run()
```

**Error**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 961, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'carousel'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\Kusal\Python\Projects\venv\Projects\Diary\Diary.py", line 47, in <module>
     DiaryApp().run()
           .
           .
           .
   File "D:\Kusal\Python\Projects\venv\Projects\Diary\Diary.py", line 22, in next
     self.root.ids.carousel.load_next(mode="next")
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: error shows that it can't find object with id `carousel` - do you have `id: carousel` in  `kv` ?

Comment: you may have to show more code - or create minimal working code with this problem.

Comment: I have edited the code. Please check it.

Comment: You should keep previuos code - I don't know in what class/widget you use `self.root.ids.carousel.load_next(mode="next")` but some classes may not have `self.root.ids` but `self.ids` or `app.root.ids`

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson is my post correct now? Please check and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the `carousel` `id` through the `root` `ids`, but that `id` is defined under the `MDScreen`, which is not the `root`. The fix is to access it through the `MDScreen` where it is defined:

```
def on_start(self):
    welcome_screen = self.root.get_screen('welcome')
    carousel = welcome_screen.ids.carousel
    carousel.loop = True
    Clock.schedule_interval(carousel.load_next, 3.0)
```